# uitableview cell value not refresh according with the ones in coredata after change

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, uitableview

I'm building master-detail application, saying master view A(TableView), second-View(tableview) B, detail-view C. data is from core-data. In secondview(tableview), popover will prompt for cell value change when user tap specific cell. After change on popover screen, dismiss popover, it return back to secondview(tableview) and update core data accordingly. And the cell value is expected to reflect the update value. 
The issue is that it doesn't work like that. The cell value still remains old ones, though the core data is update with the new value(I confirmed this via NSLOG in method --tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath. It print the cell's new value, however it display the cell's old value). I tried to put table-view:reloaddata to viewwillappear and popoverControllerDidDismissPopover method, but it still doesn't work.

I cannot figure out it. The cell value on secondView(tableView) only get update after I return the view back to Master-View A and again switch it to Second-View B.

However, the second View will reflect the new cell addition immediately, the addition is also via popover prompt for cell new value input.

Would someone please help this? Thanks.

```
-(void) popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{

    //get text from popover based on various class type

   if([popoverController.contentViewController isKindOfClass:[changecellvalueViewController class]])
   {
       NSString *thenewinputcellvalue =((changecellvalueViewController *)popoverController.contentViewController).thecellvalue.text;
       NSString *oldcellvalue=((changecellvalueViewController *)popoverController.contentViewController).thecellvalueold.text;
       if (0 != [ thenewinputcellvalue length] && oldcellvalue  !=  thenewinputcellvalue)     {

           NSManagedObjectContext *acontext =  [self.masterviewmasterController.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];

           NSManagedObject *cellTobeChanged = ((changecellvalueViewController *)popoverController.contentViewController).cellobjecttobechanged;
           [ cellTobeChanged setValue: thenewinputcellvalue forKey:@"cellvalue"];
           // Save the context.
           NSError *error = nil;
           if (![acontext save:&error])
           {
               // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
               // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
               NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
               abort();
           }


          if (![self.masterviewmasterController.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
          // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
          // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
              NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
              abort();
          }

          [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
     }
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@“cell” forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@“cell”];
    }
    NSManagedObject *celllist =  [[SELF SORTCELLS] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text =   [[celllist valueForKey:@"cellName"] description];
    NSLog(@"cell text %@", cell.textLabel.text);
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;
}
```

- (void)viewDidLoad
  {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
  // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

  // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
  // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
  [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
  [self.tableView reloadData];
  }

Comment: can you please paste some lines of your code.without that no one can help i think

Comment: check the coreData have values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if you are updating datasource of UITableView of your second-View.
You can refresh that cell value by

1. Reload that cell with updated datasource(I guess your input popover properly update datasource of your UITableView) using method -

`[tableview reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:]`

1. When input popover closes using popoverControllerDidDismissPopover delegate in your UITableViewCell
   you can update Label with value from popover

Comment: i'm thinking if there're something cache the cell value when reloading

Comment: Try to debug it ..you can check for do after input popover gets dismissed do it call delegate in Table cell?

Comment: i debug it. in cellforrowatindexpath, it returns the new cell value. but i cannot figure out why it still show old value on screen.

Comment: Log your table view object.is it case you have created two UItableView Object accidentally (may be in nib and one from code) thats why it me calling all methods properly but not updating UI.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem looks to be the logic you use to populate the table view cells. This line:

```
NSManagedObject *celllist = [[[(NSSet *) self.celltypes valueForKey:@"tocellList" ] allObjects] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

is getting an array (`allObjects`) from a set. A set has no order so each time you request this array it will have a different order. This means that your cells don't have deterministic content, you will have duplicate rows and missing rows.

Whenever the set changes, you should get the array of contents, sort it and store it. This sorted array should be used as the source of data for your table view.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Even it's the case duplicate or missing rows. it should be able to reflect on screen, right?  I tired to sort it. it still has the issue

Comment: If your log shows the correct test then it should show on screen. Also log the index path so you know where it is in the list.